# Lua random seed

Tags: random, lua, torch

I have a python program which I am trying to replicate in lua. In the python code, I have created a number of random matrices and have initially set the random seed using `np.random.seed(seed=1)`. To make it easier to debug and trace the output of my lua program, I would like to set the same random seed in my lua code also. Is this possible and if so, how?

In lua, I have tried:

```
math.randomseed(1)
```

Then, I set `a=torch.rand(2,2)` and printed `a` but different matrices are being printed when I print `a`

What I need:

In python, when I set random seed as 1 and print a 2d matrix, I get:

```
([[  4.17022005e-01,   7.20324493e-01],
       [  1.14374817e-04,   3.02332573e-01]])
```

When I print a 2d matrix in lua, I must get the same matrix(after using the same seed)

Is this possible?

Comment: `math.random` seeds the built-in random number generator and `math.random` is guaranteed to return the same sequence of numbers each time if you first seed it with `math.randomseed`. Torch however may use a different random generator so idk.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you need to use `torch.manualSeed(1)` for torch random

http://torch7.readthedocs.io/en/rtd/random/